# ASP.NET IserviceCollection AddIdentity not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a situation where I want to change the password length of ASP.NET Identity user (database-first) to lets say 4. After much research, I found I can do it from the start up class with:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

I have downloaded the packages `Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` but still AddIdentity cannot be found

Answer (score 14):

`AddIdentity` and it's related extension methods are part of ASP.NET Core Identity, which resides on the NuGet package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/).

`AddEntityFrameworkStores` is part of EntityFrameworkCore for ASP.NET Core Identity package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but now  AddEntityFrameworkStores cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this nugget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` (web project), bringing it the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` would resolve `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>`.

However, if you're writing an extension method from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` (class project), no matter which NuGet packages you install, you won't find that extension method..., until you install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`.

I think it's confusing. I used to be able to just install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` NuGet (now it's deprecated) because I don't use all the features from the `UI` package. I rather build my own views.